# Chrome is using 1 process per website instead of per tab

Tags: google-chrome

if I'm browsing a website like an online shop, or reddit and open up multiple links into tabs, Chrome will get very sluggish and slow, the page I'm currently viewing will freeze while the new tabs are trying to load in the background. When looking at Chrome's task manager all tabs under the same domain are sharing a process.

I did not change any settings, and I'm not sure how to force Chrome to use 1 process for each tab like it used to.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does Chrome group my tabs in processes and how can I stop it?](https://superuser.com/questions/207302/why-does-chrome-group-my-tabs-in-processes-and-how-can-i-stop-it)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [Chromium design document](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models), you can try using the flag `--process-per-tab`, although tabs with shared scripts or some other traits may still be lumped in the same process.