# Force Chrome to open each tab in its own process?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a powerful workstation PC with stacks of RAM. I frequently work with a web app (Mailchimp, actually) that uses a lot of blocking Javascript. In some cases it has to wait for a request to complete before unblocking, which can take several minutes. I work on several Mailchimp pages at once, and for last the few months Chrome has decided to sometimes open all of the Mailchimp pages in the one process (whyyyy??), so when the blocking request takes several minutes I'm just stuck waiting for the other tabs to start working again.

So, is there some way to force Chrome to open every tab in its own process? Googling seems to only give me results for doing the opposite, which is obviously not what I want.

---

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot of the issue (in Chrome's task manager). I still haven't found a way to solve this. The screenshot was taken after right-clicking the taskbar button of an existing window and clicking Chrome (6 times), then typing the Mailchimp address into the address bar and going to a different page on each tab. Yet they somehow still ended up joined together. This is very frustrating.

---

**EDIT2:** I learned about the cmdline switch `--process-per-tab` but even after adding that switch (and confirming with Process Explorer that Chrome is running with the switch) the problem still exists. This is quite frustrating as it absolutely was not a problem a few months ago, and it seems to be getting worse.

[image]

Comment: How do you open these multiple tabs of Mailchimp (or whatever)?

Comment: @DanielB Middle-click usually, but RMB > open in new tab seems to have the same effect.

Comment: Perhaps try opening tabs manually and then loading the web app “manually” from the address bar. Another possibility would be multiple profiles, but I’m not sure whether you can run them in parallel.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately while I suspect that would be an option (I will test of course) it would drastically slow down my workflow :(

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does Chrome group my tabs in processes and how can I stop it?](https://superuser.com/questions/207302/why-does-chrome-group-my-tabs-in-processes-and-how-can-i-stop-it)

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Actually my post mentions the cmdline switch given in the answers in the supposed dupe, and that didn't solve my problem. Therefore this isn't a dupe.

Comment: @Clonkex Yes, it's a common mistake on all such questions to recommend this option, which actually mean "process per group of script-connected tabs", default process model actually separates tabs even stricter. But the linked documentation page also describes what you ended up figuring out yourself and there's also another answer which quotes the same from the doc (quite badly, I should say). However, if there was no helpful _answers_, it doesn't mean that your _question_ isn't a duplicate, there are simply no more solutions we can suggest.

Comment: @Clonkex It's actually quite unusual to see tabs being grouped now, because [Site Isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation) is turned on by default and the `--renderer-process-limit` option (which can force the behavior you see) doesn't work for me with it being on.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 When a question specifically mentions that the accepted answer of another question doesn't answer the question in their situation, then it's not a dupe. That's all I meant. But yeah, it definitely still groups tabs into a single process if you open enough of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me that in recent months I've been keeping a lot more tabs open than I traditionally have, and I wondered if Chrome was trying to limit the memory use of so many tabs by combining some. The increased tab count was due to my habit of dragging windows of tabs related to unfinished projects over to my other monitor and keeping them for later ("later" often being many months).

I had four windows with a heap of tabs in each so I grabbed Session Buddy and saved each window as a session that I could restore later, which reduced my tab count from about 64 to 15. Immediately after doing that Chrome stopped combining my Mailchimp tabs.

Based on the evidence, I'd say Chrome tries to prevent memory usage going too high when large numbers of tabs are open by combining some into a single process. That means **the fix is to reduce the number of open tabs**. I'm going to consider this the correct answer until proven otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

> By default, the Chrome browser creates an entirely separate operating system process for every single tab or extra extension you are using. If you have several different tabs open and a variety of third party extensions installed you may notice five or more processes running simultaneously.

[Source](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/disabling-multiple-processes-google-chrome-33767.html)

Comment: This doesn't appear the be the case in the last couple of months or so. At least, not consistently. I need a way to make it consistent.

Comment: This appears to never have been true.